# how to concatenate two getElementsBy 

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
var profileLinks = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i<searchResult.length; ++i) 
{
    var profileLink=searchResult[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    profileLinks[i]=profileLink[0].href;
    alert(i+1+" of "+searchResult.length+" "+profileLinks[i]);
}
```

It seems like I should be able to make it more concise by using this:

```
//alternate construction (why doesn't this work?)

var searchResult = document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto")
```

returns a selection, therefore you cannot chain functions to it. You need to specify an element directly not a whole selection, for example this would work correctly.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto")[0].getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Because document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto")[0] points to an object and not to a selection of objects.

Comment: thank you very much.  so if i just iterate thru the instances, document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto") [0].getElementsByTagName("a"); substituting [i] for [0] i should get what i wanted

Comment: iterating through 
document.getElementsByClassName("f_foto")[ x ], and checking for .getElementsByTagName("a") 

will return all the anchor elements within elements with className="f_foto". If that is what you are after it will work yes. Though as other mentioned beware with IE8 and below compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Use `querySelectorAll()` instead:

```
var searchResult = document.querySelectorAll(".f_foto a");
```

IE 8 supports `querySelectorAll()` but not `getElementsByClassName()`, so this should give you better compatibility too.

For full compatibility, stick to your original code or use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have libraries - or even modern browsers. You are looking for the css selector `$('.f_foto a')` in jQuery, or `$$('.f_foto a')` in Prototoype/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You call getElementsByTagName on a node, not an array, which is what is returned by getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `getElementsByTagName` can only be applied to an element node, but the result of `getElementsByClassName` is surely going to be a *list* of nodes. You'll either have to pick one (`[0]`?) or iterate over the collection (make sure it's not empty!).